# Importing certain modules suppresses Flask console output

Tags: python, flask, output, eyed3

I'm writing an application in Flask, that consists of two files, `app.py` and `tags.py`. `app.py` imports `tags.py`, which in turn contains `from eyed3 import load`. [Eyed3](http://eyed3.nicfit.net/index.html) is a Python module to extract mp3 tags from files. For some reason import of Eyed3 suppresses Flask's console output. Usually when starting Flask with `python app.py` returns:

```
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:17000/
```

When Eyed3 is imported, this line doesn't appear. It doesn't matter, whether it is `import eyed3` or `from eyed3 import load`, or if import is in `app.py` or `tags.py`, or Flask has debug mode on/off. I even tried to run

```
import sys
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
```

just after import or before `app.run()`, no success. Why and how does mere import of a module hide console output? How can i restore it?

**Edit:** Order of import doesn't matter. Nothing happens, if i import Eyed3 before Flask, error still holds. Does it have to do with [this line of code](https://bitbucket.org/nicfit/eyed3/src/97905ecfcd6c8f8df0349582b90258b154e583b5/src/eyed3/utils/log.py?at=default#cl-54)?

Comment: That is bizarre isnt it. I can replicate it with minimal code, just to reassure you you're not on your own. sys.stdout looks sane just before app.run() as far as I can tell, and going through the code that executes at import time doesn't reveal the offender yet

Comment: What happens if you import eyed3 *before* you import Flask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm willing to bet it has something to do with the logging manipulations that EyeD3 is doing in this file: https://bitbucket.org/nicfit/eyed3/src/97905ecfcd6c8f8df0349582b90258b154e583b5/src/eyed3/utils/log.py?at=default